# Guide to Repository Layout and Build Promotion with Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Usual story, new to artificatory and looking for a jump start.

Can anyone point me at a decent how-to post for using Artifactory (free version) with Jenkins in a deployment pipeline?

I figure I'm likely to want to:

1. setup several repos for dev thru production (any standards for this?)
2. have jenkins publish artifacts to the first repo using the artifactory plugin - limiting the amount of builds kept in artifactory.
3. promote builds from one repo to next as release to next environment - again deleting older builds

I just need a good guide/example to get started...

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you check the [User Guide](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=25067914)? It covers all your questions perfectly well. Here are:

   1. [Creating repositories](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories) (re the standards - the preconfigured repos reflect the standards).
   2. [Working with Jenkins](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+%28Hudson%29+Artifactory+Plug-in)
   3. [Jenkins Release Management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ReleaseManagementwithStagingandPromotion)
2. Keep in mind that all the promotion functionality is available in Pro version only. That includes both [simple move operation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem) (not recommended for promotion pipeplines) and extremely powerful [release management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ReleaseManagementwithStagingandPromotion), based on [build integration](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) with [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+%28Hudson%29+Artifactory+Plug-in).

Comment: Sadly, Jenkins Release Management looks only possible with Maven or Gradle build jobs.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane You can do the same using plain REST API calls or [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/)